# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath' because could not find TensorFlow Lite files

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, gradle, tensorflow-lite

I tried to build a TensorFlow lite application with **`nightly tensorflow lite`**.

However, it occurred eight identical errors like the following error.
I wanted to search for a solution about this problem, but I couldn't find out it from anywhere (Of course, it can be just that I couldn't find out it).

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 8 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-local:0.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/Users/JJ/.m2/repository/org/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite-local/0.0.0/tensorflow-lite-local-0.0.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite-local/0.0.0/tensorflow-lite-local-0.0.0.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite-local/0.0.0/tensorflow-lite-local-0.0.0.pom
       - http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite-local/0.0.0/tensorflow-lite-local-0.0.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

And, this is my **`build.gradle (Project)`**.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven {  // Only for snapshot artifacts
            name 'ossrh-snapshot'
            url 'http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Plus, this is my **`build.gradle (App)`**.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "android.example.com.tflitecamerademo"
        // Required by Camera2 API.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "tflite"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {  // Only for snapshot artifacts
        name 'ossrh-snapshot'
        url 'http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Uncomment if you want to use a local repo.
        // mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {  // Only for snapshot artifacts
            name 'ossrh-snapshot'
            url 'http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'

    // Build off of nightly TensorFlow Lite
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'
    // Use local TensorFlow library
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-local:0.0.0'
}

def targetFolder = "src/main/assets"
def modelFloatDownloadUrl = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/mobilenet_v1_2018_02_22/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224.tgz"
def modelQuantDownloadUrl = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/mobilenet_v1_2018_08_02/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quant.tgz"
def localCacheFloat = "build/intermediates/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224.tgz"
def localCacheQuant = "build/intermediates/mmobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quant.tgz"


task downloadModelFloat(type: DownloadUrlTask) {
    doFirst {
        println "Downloading ${modelFloatDownloadUrl}"
    }
    sourceUrl = "${modelFloatDownloadUrl}"
    target = file("${localCacheFloat}")
}

task downloadModelQuant(type: DownloadUrlTask) {
    doFirst {
        println "Downloading ${modelQuantDownloadUrl}"
    }
    sourceUrl = "${modelQuantDownloadUrl}"
    target = file("${localCacheQuant}")
}

task unzipModelFloat(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'downloadModelFloat') {
    doFirst {
        println "Unzipping ${localCacheFloat}"
    }
    from tarTree("${localCacheFloat}")
    into "${targetFolder}"
}

task unzipModelQuant(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'downloadModelQuant') {
    doFirst {
        println "Unzipping ${localCacheQuant}"
    }
    from tarTree("${localCacheQuant}")
    into "${targetFolder}"
}

task cleanUnusedFiles(type: Delete, dependsOn: ['unzipModelFloat', 'unzipModelQuant']) {
    delete fileTree("${targetFolder}").matching {
        include "*.pb"
        include "*.ckpt.*"
        include "*.pbtxt.*"
        include "*.quant_info.*"
        include "*.meta"
    }
}


// Ensure the model file is downloaded and extracted before every build
preBuild.dependsOn unzipModelFloat
preBuild.dependsOn unzipModelQuant
preBuild.dependsOn cleanUnusedFiles


class DownloadUrlTask extends DefaultTask {
    @Input
    String sourceUrl

    @OutputFile
    File target

    @TaskAction
    void download() {
        ant.get(src: sourceUrl, dest: target)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

I have resolved this problem.

### 1. Commenting a line

First of all, you should comment the following line `implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-local:0.0.0'` in the **build.gradle (app)**

#### Before

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'

    // Build off of nightly TensorFlow Lite
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'
    // Use local TensorFlow library
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-local:0.0.0'
}
```

#### After

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'

    // Build off of nightly TensorFlow Lite
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'
    // Use local TensorFlow library
    // implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-local:0.0.0'
}
```

### 2. Adding a line in AndroidManifest.xml

If your **AndroidManifest.xml** code has a `<activity> </activity>` pair and it includes a `<intent-filter> </intent-filter>` pair, then you should add a line of `android:exported = true`.

#### Before

```xml
<activity android:name="com.example.android.tflitecamerademo.CameraActivity"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

#### After

```xml
<activity android:name="com.example.android.tflitecamerademo.CameraActivity"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```